# How do I extract .bin files into the original files?

Tags: archive

I have a .bin archive with an accompanying .cue file. I want to extract the original constituent files.

I DO NOT want to convert to ISO, or to MOUNT them, unless somehow this gives me access to the original files.

Basically there is an .EXE inside of the .bin which I need access to.

The other thread on this question did not help me, so I am asking a new one.

Comment: The `.bin` extension doesn't really tell us much about the type of file. Could you run `file <filename.bin>`, and paste the output?

Comment: emicd1.bin: data

Comment: eh mounting a bin IS getting access to the files inside the bin ;) (old method on this: http://maketecheasier.com/mount-iso-bin-and-cue-files-from-nautilus/2009/05/23 )

Answer (score 1):

A good solution would be [bchunk](http://he.fi/bchunk/), also called BinChunker, which is available for both, Linux and Unix.

You can install it via Terminal: `sudo apt-get install bchunk`

**Usage: bchunk [-v] [-r] [-p (PSX)] [-w (wav)] [-s (swabaudio)]** (bchunk man page)
           
**Example:**

> `bchunk foo.bin foo.cue foo`
>         -v  Verbose mode
>         -r  Raw mode for MODE2/2352: write all 2352 bytes from offset 0 (VCD/MPEG)
>         -p  PSX mode for MODE2/2352: write 2336 bytes from offset 24
>             (default MODE2/2352 mode writes 2048 bytes from offset 24)
>         -w  Output audio files in WAV format
>         -s  swabaudio: swap byte order in audio tracks

Please refer to the link above, for more information and if you come across any problems, please edit your post and i'll get back to you!