# Using .bin files

Tags: mount, firefox, java, virtualization

Hello I have around 20 video files that I bought off an online tutorial website.

In the introductory tutorial they said that you can play the .bin files using daemon tools.

But how about linux? Daemon tools is not available for linux so what must I do? Is their any equivalent or alternative way of playing .bin files?

Also these bins , upon mounting , will open up in a browser utilizing ActiveX content.
Is it possible to achieve this with Java in Firefox?

Comment: Can you mount these files with the Archive Mounter? Else see http://askubuntu.com/questions/111383/how-do-i-extract-bin-files-into-the-original-files - unfortunately we do not know much on the content of these files, and with what application they were created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok , Now I understood. you can use `bchunk`.
use bchunk to convert your .bin files into ISO and then mount the ISO file.

you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install bchunk
```

usage:

```
bchunk filename.bin  filename.iso
```

credit : [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1905315) & [Ubuntugeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-convert-bincue-files-to-iso-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Don't you need a .cue file for the bchunk to work?

Answer (score 0):

I once played a .bin video using just vlc
give it a try! you can install vlc using this command :

> sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: Already tried out VLC , but as I said , its not a simple multimedia video , its a CD which upon mounting upons up as a browser

Comment: then try @rajagenupula's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try AcetoneISO. It worked quite well for me without the need of manually converting to an .iso file. It has also got a user-friendly GUI.